# When to prefer “是……的” over “了” in “是谁把你送到机场的？” or “谁把你送到了机场？”?

Tags: grammar, meaning

When to prefer “是……的”· over “了”? Which one of the following is correct?

- 是谁把你送到机场的？
- 谁把你送到了机场？

Comment: The 了 sentence could mean implicitly that you're supposed to go somewhere where else but someone mistakenly took you to the airport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally do not see any difference between the following two interrogative sentences. If there is no more context, I do not see preferences on which one to use over the other. In fact, you can have “了” also in the first sentence, which still makes no difference (see #3). As to the word “的”, it is the result of a reduction of the word “人” or “那个人”. It also uses the inversed form of the question. Otherwise, it would be like #4.

(1) 是谁把你送到机场的？

(2) 谁把你送到了机场？

(3) 是谁把你送到机场了？

(4) 把你送到机场的那个人是谁？

Answer (score 1):

- 是谁把你送到机场的？ Who escorted/accompanied you to the airport?
- 是谁把你送到了机场？- Who escorted/accompanied you to (reach/arrive at) the airport?

Note that 送到 simply means "send/escort/accompany to", however, it implies "send/escort/accompany someone/something to reach/arrive at the destination" when modified by 了, which indicated the completion of the act.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them is correct,他们之间基本上没有区别，你都可以说。